# I declare the objects inside the array ,I want to pass these data into backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

In the backend, I want to store values like the below image. It has the sItem array and it has many objects. each object has three variables like subitem, qty, and price.

[image]

In the frontend I used the console log ,its displays values like the below image second object attribute values also go with object one values. I want to pass it to the second object. Actually, i want to store each object's value inside each object.

[image]

My react javascript code like below

```
  const onSubmit = () => {
    var names = inputFields.map(function (inputField) {
      return inputField["subItem","availability","price"];
    });

    const data = 
{
  "sItem":[
{
  subItem: names.toString(),
  availability: names.toString(),
  price: names.toString(),
},
{
  
}

  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, you want to ask how to transfer to backend, or how to merge data? In the former case, the data can be transferred using *axios* or *fetch*

Comment: @lan my question is In the database have some structure to store the data (image 1 describes it). then I want to transfer the data into that structure in the frontend to the backend using Axios and store it.Then how to pass that data in frontend with that structure ( I want to store multiple objects it one array) . I want a frontend query to pass the data into the backend.  sItem[obj1 {subitem:"",qty:"",price:""},obj2 {subitem:"",qty:"",price:""}]

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about API that backend side create with database and frontend can use it as object array in javascript.See more [API](https://imgopt.infoq.com/fit-in/1200x2400/filters:quality(80)/filters:no_upscale()/articles/api-first-integration/en/resources/1Figure-1-The-role-of-APIs-1604606456889.jpg) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).